# Create a new JSON after manipulating json values in angular6

Tags: json, angular

Below is my JSON

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "Key": "doc/1996-78/ERROR-doc-20200103.xlsx"
>     }
>  },
> {
>     "Key": "doc/1996-78/SUCCESS-doc-20200103.xlsx"
>  },
>  {
>     "Key": "doc/1996-78/PENDING-doc-20200103.xlsx"
>     }
>   ]
> ```
>
> First i want to split key value by backslash and after that will split the [2] json value by hyphen and then will check in string that if there is SUCCESS/PENDING/ERROR word found in the newly spitted JSON. If any word is present would like to add new status field and add Done/Processing/Failure respective values in newly created JSON. this is a dynamic json so without manipulating it i can't get status value

This is what i would like to achive in my new JSON

```
[
 {
  "Key": "doc/1996-78/ERROR-doc-20200103.xlsx",
   "status":"Failure"
   }
},
{
  "Key": "doc/1996-78/SUCCESS-doc-20200103.xlsx",
  "Status":"Done"
},
{
  "Key": "doc/1996-78/PENDING-doc-20200103.xlsx",
   "Status":"Processing"
  }
]
```

As i'm new to this kindly let me know how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `includes` function and if `true` then add string.

Try my code:

```js
let myJson = [
  {
    "Key": "doc/1996-78/ERROR-doc-20200103.xlsx"
  },

  {
    "Key": "doc/1996-78/SUCCESS-doc-20200103.xlsx"
  },
  {
    "Key": "doc/1996-78/PENDING-doc-20200103.xlsx"
  },
  {
    "Key": "doc/1996-78/WRONG-doc-20200103.xlsx"
  }
];

myJson = myJson.map(obj => ({
  ...obj,
  "Status": obj.Key.includes("ERROR") ? 'Failure' : obj.Key.includes('SUCCESS') ? 'Done' : obj.Key.includes('PENDING') ? 'Processing' : false
}))

console.log(myJson)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(let object of objectArra) {
     if(object.key === 'doc....')
      object['status']="Failure";
     else if (object.key === 'doc..')
      object['status'] = "Done";
     else if....
}
```

Iterate on object array if the key is equal to that you want status is "failure", you insert a status property in the object with "Failure" as value ...

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in the following way

```
yourArrayName.forEach((val)=>{
  if(val.Key.includes('ERROR')){
    val['Status']="Failure"
  }
   else if(val.Key.includes('SUCCESS')){
    val['Status']="Done"
  }
   else if(val.Key.includes('PENDING')){
    val['Status']="Processing"
  }
})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for response but how will i check if success,errror are present in the JSON file i mean how to split values and check pls help me on this

Answer (score 1):

## How to do it in ES 6

The key advantage is the use of Regex which makes it more flexible to other requirements than `includes`.

```
const data = [
 {
    "Key": "doc/1996-78/ERROR-doc-20200103.xlsx"
 },
 {
    "Key": "doc/1996-78/SUCCESS-doc-20200103.xlsx"
 },
 {
    "Key": "doc/1996-78/PENDING-doc-20200103.xlsx"
 }
];

data.map((entry) => {
   let status;
   if (/^.*ERROR.*$/.test(entry.Key)) {
       status = 'Failure';
   } else if (/^.*SUCCESS.*$/.test(entry.Key)) {
       status = 'Done'
   } else if (/^.*PENDING.*$/.test(entry.Key)) {
       status = 'Processing'
   }
   return {...entry, status};
});
```